# Exporting dataframe to csv not showing first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to export my df to a .csv file. The df has just two columns of data: the image name (.jpg), and the 'value_counts' of how many times that .jpg name occurs in the 'concat_Xenos.csv' file, i.e:

```
M116_13331848_13109013329679.jpg    19
M116_13331848_13109013316679.jpg    14
M116_13331848_13109013350679.jpg    12
M116_13331848_13109013332679.jpg    11
etc. etc. etc....
```

However, whenever I export the df, the .csv file only displayes the 'value_counts' column. How do I modify this?

My code is as follows:

```
concat_Xenos = r'C:\file_path\concat_Xenos.csv'

df = pd.read_csv(concat_Xenos, header=None, index_col=False)[0]
counts = df.value_counts()

export_csv = counts.to_csv (r'C:\file_path\concat_Xenos_valuecounts.csv', index=None, header=False)
```

Thanks! If any clarification is needed please ask :)

R

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the first column is set as index.

Use `index=True`:

```
export_csv = counts.to_csv (r'C:\file_path\concat_Xenos_valuecounts.csv', index=True, header=False)
```

or you can reset your index before exporting.

```
counts.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

Comment: Simple as that! Thank you @Rakesh , that has worked. However, now the csv is also counting the header in the 'value_counts' command, and is including the row 'filename, 1' at the bottom of the new csv file. How do I prevent my code from including headers in the counts? In line two of my script above changing the 'header=None' to 'True' or 'False' just returns errors.